# How to get the weak (p,q) condition of the complex ordinary differential equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laurent-series

A equation satisfies the weak (p,q) condition, where q indicates its solutions' multiplicity of the pole at $z=0$ is q and p indicates p distinct Laurent singular part $\sum\limits_{k=-q}^{-1}c_k z^k$.

To find the weak $(p,q)$ condition of the equation, we substitute the Laurent series $ w(z)=\sum\limits_{k=-q}^{\infty}c_k z^k,q>0,c_{-q}\neq 0 $ into the equation.

Let us set the equation as $w^{(4)} + w'' + \frac{1}{2}w^2 - cw-b =0$. Its weak $(p,q)$ condition is (1,4).

I want to konw how to canculate the weak (p,q) condition so that I can use software such as mathematica to get the weak (p,q) condition.

[the meaning of p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3HYI.png)

Comment: What exactly is $p$? Some dimension of the solution space with singularities at $z=0$? I can see that in the leading terms you get $q(q+1)(q+2)(q+3)c_{-q}z^{-q-4}+\frac12c_{-q}^2z^{-2q}=0$ which requires $q=4$ to balance. The next necessary term is for the power $z^{-2}$ to assimilate the leading term of $w''$, but that does not exclude terms for $z^{-3}$.

Comment: Thank you. $p$ should be the  number of solutions'  Laurent series with different major parts $\sum\limits_{k=-q}^{-1}c_k z^k$.  In the article I read, the author directly uses the number of all possible values of $c_{-q}$ as $p$

Comment: The exponents of the leading terms in the expansion of the terms of the equation, seen as linear functions, form half-spaces, the intersection of them a convex set. $p$ would then be the number of vertices, of different balances of the leading terms.

Comment: You need to restrict this count to vertices with integer $q$ as solution, otherwise you get Puisseux series with broken powers.